# Can't set bitmap to button

Tags: winapi

As the title says, I can't get it working. The button works and looks like normal...

```
HWND hWndButtonGetRes = CreateWindowEx(NULL,
            "BUTTON",
            "Get Results",
            WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,
            50,
            220,
            100,
            24,
            hwnd,
            (HMENU)IDC_MAIN_BUTTON,
            GetModuleHandle(NULL),
            NULL);


    SendMessage(hWndButtonGetRes, BM_SETIMAGE, (WPARAM)IMAGE_BITMAP, (LPARAM)myBitmap);
```

Edit:

The bitmap is being loaded this way:

```
myBitmap = LoadBitmap(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(BM))
```

where BM is

```
BM          BITMAP DISCARDABLE       "bitmap.bmp"
#define BM   1
```

I am running Windows 7 64.

Comment: Are you testing this on Windows XP ? I have faced similar problem before... Best regards.

Comment: Without an sscce this question is hard to answer. Give us enough to reproduce your scenario.

Comment: How is `myBitmap` being loaded?  What value is `BM_SETIMAGE` returning?

Comment: On Windows XP it appears that you need to set the `BS_BITMAP` style on the control to be able to display a bitmap on a button.

Comment: What's the return value of `LoadBitmap`? Is the code inside a DLL?